# Android: how to do background clickable effect by programmatically?

Tags: android, android-event

I have a background for button.

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/whiteTransparent50" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/whiteTransparent50" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

But this is not my want. Because i have a one main image. And image has a two section which i call A and B. When i press A section main image is changing to C image. and When i press B section main image is changing to D image. So my solution is:

```
A.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
//                    action pressed
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(R.drawable.C_image)
                                .into(iv);
                        return true;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(R.drawable.main_image)
                                .into(iv);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        B.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
//                    action pressed
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(R.drawable.D_image)
                                .into(iv);
                        return true;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(R.drawable.main_image)
                                .into(iv);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But when i do it setOnclickListener's not working?
So my thought is:
(android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true) it's working.(android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true") it's not working.
How to do it?

Comment: You can add this to your view in layout **android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"** for only effect, colorPrimary will be fill

Comment: are you understand my question?

Comment: i want to change button_click.xml by A.setOnTouchListener or other code.

Comment: Because I'm using glide. and it's not problem of changing only one button.